# excel vba check if command button and checkbox exists

Tags: vba, excel, exists, commandbutton

I have a script that uses checkboxes and command buttons, and there is a macro that resets them to default on every sheet.

```
'opt button reset
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Sheets(i).Shapes("Option Button 1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
    Next i

'cb reset
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOff
Next i
```

The problem is that, if there is a sheet that has no checkbox or opt button, the script does not work

What I want to do is to check if the cb and ob exists and execute the script only than.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. Quickest way: On Error Resume Next

   ```
   On Error Resume Next
   For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
     Sheets(i).Shapes("Option Button 1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn   'opt button reset
     Sheets(i).Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOff   'cb reset
   Next i
   ```
2. Loop through objects and match name

   ```
   For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
     For Each myControl In Sheets(i).Shapes
       If myControl.Name = "CheckBox1" Then
         myControl.Value = xlOff
       ElseIf myControl.Name = "Option Button 1" Then
         myControl.Value = xlOn
       End If
     Next myControl
   Next i
   ```

Comment: the second one does not work, I get the error: object doesn't support this property of method. I find the second one fancyer :-)

Comment: You actually can't have spaces in the name of a control.  Could you verify the name of the opt button?

Comment: It was with spaces, and it was working with the first solution. Now I did it without spaces, and the same error appears. Is it possible that it is because I use the Workbook_BeforeSave function?

Comment: ok, I found the problem:
`myControl.ControlFormat.Value` is the working version :) Thanks you for the help